# Java JDBC executeUpdate arraycopy: length -1434 is negative

Tags: java, db2-luw

I've got problem with calling stored procedure in DB2. If i run it without java, it'll work fine. Can someone help me with that? 
The problem does not depend on message variable and i can't get whats wrong with it.

Here's the code:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("call tb.proc(?,?,?,?, ?)");
        cstmt.setString(1, message);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(4, Types.INTEGER);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(5, Types.CHAR);
        cstmt.executeUpdate();
```

SP definition, as requested, this one calls other stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tb.proc (IN MESSAGE VARCHAR(300), OUT RESPONSE VARCHAR(300), OUT RESPMESSAGE VARCHAR(300), OUT E INTEGER,  OUT ESTATE CHAR(5))

BEGIN

    DECLARE varCode VARCHAR(300);
    DECLARE varUPD_SID VARCHAR(300);
    DECLARE varP_ZAPR VARCHAR(300);
    DECLARE varDATE_PLREM VARCHAR(300);
    DECLARE varDATE_PLSP VARCHAR(300);
    DECLARE varP_XAR VARCHAR(300);
    DECLARE varUPD_TIME VARCHAR(300);
    DECLARE varUPD_USER VARCHAR(300);
    DECLARE varOperation VARCHAR(300);
    DECLARE varNINV VARCHAR(300);
    DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER;
    DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5);

    DECLARE ErrorCode CHAR(5) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
        BEGIN
        SET E = SQLCODE, ESTATE = SQLSTATE;
        END;

    CALL TB.SPLITMESSAGE(MESSAGE, varCode, varUPD_SID, varNinv, varOperation, varP_Zapr, varDate_Plrem, varDate_Plsp,  varP_Xar);
    CALL TB.VALIDATEFORMAT(varCode, varUPD_SID, varNinv, varOperation, varP_Zapr, varDate_Plrem, varDate_Plsp,  varP_Xar, ErrorCode);
    IF ErrorCode IS NULL
        THEN
            CALL TB.VALIDATEFIELDS(varCode, varUPD_SID, varNinv, varOperation, varP_Zapr, varDate_Plrem, varDate_Plsp,  varP_Xar, ErrorCode);
    END IF;

    CALL TB.PROC2(Message, varCode, varUPD_SID, varNinv, varOperation, varP_Zapr, varDate_Plrem, varDate_Plsp,  varP_Xar, ErrorCode,
                            RESPONSE, RESPMESSAGE);

END
```

and here's the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: arraycopy: length -1434 is negative
    at java.base/java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.x.a(x.java:102)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.x.a(x.java:150)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.uw.UWReply.b(UWReply.java:62)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.x.c(x.java:360)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.x.d(x.java:375)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.x.f(x.java:646)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.y.ic(y.java:4622)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.y.hc(y.java:4607)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.c(ab.java:3031)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.b(ab.java:3021)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.b(ab.java:2911)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.a(ab.java:2767)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.b(ab.java:2692)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.a(ab.java:2606)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.a(ab.java:173)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.b(ab.java:84)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.b(p.java:69)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.rb.c(rb.java:244)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.rc(po.java:3520)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.wc(po.java:3644)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.b(po.java:4421)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.CallableStatement.ic(CallableStatement.java:194)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.CallableStatement.executeUpdate(CallableStatement.java:173)
```

Comment: We need to see the definition of the stored procedure, of course, and of any tables it uses.

Comment: Well, that is complicated. Stored procedure itself calls several other stored procedures, that process incoming message, BTW if i run stored procedure without java, it works fine.  Anyway i am adding sp definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a [known issue](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/4937745) - you need to upgrade to the latest DB2 JDBC driver.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i've updated the driver and it works now.

Comment: btw, are there any workarounds if it is not possible?

Comment: Request if you can mention the version which was failing and mention the version to which you upgraded to as a comment perhaps - which may help someone in future.

Comment: It is always better to upgrade the version - for any other workaround, you will have to do some digging with the exact condition and combination when you see the error.

Comment: Failing version: 4.14.111 upgraded to 4.21.29